# Integer array switch Android JAva

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am trying to do a simple convert units application. I have 2 spinners, which one of them containing an array that says the different types of units.

And when I press the Convert button based on what is selected in both spinners should do something.

Example: Spinner 1 - Selected POUNDS US / Spinner2 - Selected KiloGrams
Them when I press the convert button it converts it and display in another textbox.

My problem is I will have to check every single time what is selected in each spinner... and that would be a lot of if, else if statements and I was hoping if I could do it using a switch with a Integer Array. Here is my code to understand it a little more.

```
private void mass() {
    num = (Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString()));

    int position1 = sInput.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int position2 = sResult.getSelectedItemPosition();
    int[] position = new int[] {position1, position2};

     if(position[0] == 1 && position[1] == 6) {
         setValue((Double.toString(round(num / 2.2))));
     } else if(position1 == 6 && position2 == 1) {
         setValue((Double.toString(round(num * 2.2))));
     }
}
```

The array position holds the values selected in the spinner. Is there a way of doing a switch statement using something like position[0,0], position[0,1], etc., or an even better approach than that?

Comment: Your code is incorrectly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, for converting mass to and from different units, I would go through an intermediate unit.

eg. lets say I have the following

```
final int TYPE_KG = 0;
final int TYPE_POUNDS = 1;

// these two values come from your spinners
int sourceUnitType; // eg 0=kg, 1=pounds, ...
int destUnitType;   // same types as the source unit type
```

Then you can convert the source number into your intermediate units, like kilograms, using a function

```
double convertMassToKg(int sourceUnitType, double source)
{
    switch (sourceUnitType)
    {
    case TYPE_KG:
        return source;
    case TYPE_POUND:
        return source * 0.453592;
    }
}
```

then convert the intermediate value into the destination units

```
double convertKgToMass(int destinationUnitType, double kilos)
{
    switch (destinationUnitType)
    {
    case TYPE_KG:
        return kilos;
    case TYPE_POUND:
        return kilos / 0.453592;
    }
}
```

That's just my take on the problem anyway.
What values can your spinners take? Because it doesn't make sense to let somebody try to convert kilometers to kilograms for example, so depending upon how you have broken up your program (i.e. is this form just for converting mass?) then perhaps you can approach it a little differently.

You could let the user select the source type in the first spinner, and then update the second spinner with only those types which make sense, eg if the first spinner is selected to "kilometers" then the second could have the options "miles", "centimeters", "yards", etc.

Comment: Well actually what happens is depend on the button the user presses the spinner loads a different set of values, speed, mass, degrees, etc.. and i want the user to be able to convert from one type to another and the opposite as well. 
Ex: if he selects pounds > he also can be able to convert to miligrams, oz, kg, etc.. there is other options.

Comment: Yep, I understand. What do you think of this idea? I think it has its merits. A lot more typing than @StinePike's answer but perhaps a little more readable. Either way, I think there are some good options :)

Comment: If you have 100s of these conversions, that's a lot of code duplication. You can probably combine the 2 functions into 1 by passing in an additional parameter, since the only difference seems to be `*` VS `/`. You can just set a variable in the switch and have the calculations happen after the `switch`.

Comment: Some conversions are more than simple multiply/divide, like Celsius to Fahrenheit or Celsius to Kelvin (maybe these are the only ones). Anyway, just my idea, apparently not a popular one ;)

Comment: I'm using a different but similar approach. Thank you for the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, There might be better idea than that

initially create a 2d array a which dimension is

```
a[ number of first spinner's item][number of second spinner's item]
```

initialized the array with the conversion factor. For example

if kg to pouds conversion factor is 2.2. In your spinner 1 kg's index is 1 and in spinner 2 kg's index is 3 then

```
a[1][3] = 2.2
```

now when the convert button is pressed do the following

```
result = value*a[spiner1 index][spinner 2 index]
```

**Visible Advantages:**

- no if else , easy computation
- all conversion in a single array, easy to add/edit/change

**Visible Disadvantages**

- extra memory of array and extra initialization operations

Comment: Good idea. I wonder what to do about converting incompatible units - maybe could store `NaN` in combinations which are invalid...

Comment: @WayneUroda yes or can store negative value to identify.. but usually in these cases all two pairs are convartible

Comment: yeah I thought maybe negative could be a valid conversion in some cases... I guess not though :) I was thinking the case where the user might try "km" to "kg", not sure if the program would allow that from the given information